# TS2950CT50 Voltage Regulator +5V confusing specs / usage

Tags: voltage-regulator

The [datasheet for the TS2950CT50](http://www.rapidonline.com/pdf/156892_da_en_01.pdf) voltage regulator only provides information on the series TS2950C and TS2951C. From what I can tell, TS2950CT50 is a model within that series, which is a fixed +5v regulator. But the circuit diagram in the datasheet only shows how the model TS2951A can be used to provide a custom voltage output. But it gives no information on how I might use the TS2950CT50 (which I think is purely a +5v fixed model, is that correct?)

Please can someone give me a circuit diagram of how to use TS2950CT50? The input will be between 10 and 15 volts. I will be drawing current between 1mA and 90mA.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page 5-6, left drawing. That's all you need to do.

Capacitance value from the text is minimum 1uF (page 1). I'd say a 2.2uF input capacitance wouldn't go wrong either.

So, basically just (and I feel I'm being very kind by redrawing it):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS3oJl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I feel embarrassed, don't know how I missed it. Thank you!

Comment: ;-) No worries. We all have our days. I'm just being a bit mean today.

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the datasheet properly.

[image]

That means TS2950CT50 is a positive 5 volts regulator.

For connection see this:

[image]

Use high quality capacitor with exact capacitance for best performance. ;)

Comment: Thank you! I saw that table, but when I glanced at that diagram it looked distinctly like it had more pins. Very daft of me!!

Comment: Its allright, Your problem is solved i guess ;)

Answer (score 3):

This part looks like a knock-off the [LP2950](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lp2951.pdf).

In any case, there are only three connections, so the application circuit is as shown on the datasheet:

[image]

Be sure to follow the recommendations for capacitors on the data sheet exactly. The only real gotcha I see is that they do **not** say that you can (or can't) use a ceramic capacitor on the output. Do not take this as permission to use one- I suggest following the recommendations in the above-linked TI datasheet and add a 1\$\Omega\$ series resistor if you do use a ceramic output capacitor. The input cap can be ceramic with no issues.

Comment: Thank you so much - I'm terribly embarrassed that I missed that!!

Comment: They do specify that the ESR cannot be above 5Ohm, that lower ESR is better and that resonance should be above 500kHz. I'm too lazy to ponder, but could a 1/4W add enough inductance to modify resonance? *shrug* 1ohm fits the bill though. I have used the same series without fail with 2.2u 16V MLCCs, but no measurements of ripples done, because never needed to.

Comment: There is no guarantee of **instability** but some units may well oscillate at some load current and some temperature. I'd prefer to give that kind of excitement a pass.